# Intuition why $(ab \mod m) = (a\mod m )\times( b\mod m) $

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I've had quite easy time imagining why addition would be 'persistent'$\mod m$ but with multiplication it's not that obvious. I've seen proofs of it, but none have helped me internalise it. Any tips on how to think about it? Thanks.

Comment: $(a+hm)(b+km)=ab+(hkm+ak+bh)m$

Comment: Perhaps thinking about multiplication as repeated addition? It seems reasonable that repeatedly applying a 'persistent' operation would yield something 'persistent'.

Comment: The best "intuition" probably is understanding the proof - which is just the above formula, considered modulo $m$.

Comment: You have to be very careful writing $a\bmod m$ as a binary function. Your statement, as one answer points out, is not true if you define $a\bmod m$ to be an integer. But if you mean it is the map that sends $a$ to its corresponding element of $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$, then it is true.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps because you are missing part of the formula?
(A * B) mod C = (A mod C * B mod C) mod C

Comment: It would be useful to find an example where the OP's given formula fails.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews A=2, B=2, C=4,  (A * B) mod C gives 0, while (A mod C * B mod C) gives 4... that's where you need the last mod C so: (A mod C * B mod C)=0.

Comment: I know, I meant, that should be in your answer, so you explain why you need the extra term. (As it is, it is possible that the OP means $a\bmod m$ to mean the corresponding element of $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$, in which case, you don't need to change the formula.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sometimes the question seems more a basic issue, like in this one.  If I start adding math rigorousness in the answer like corresponding elements of a ring of integers, the OP might get lost.  I prefer something more direct, like he understands the persistence of mod m in addition, multiplication should be explainable quite well with same persistence, I thought he had a bad formula.  I could have written the proof by Quotient-Remainder Theorem and confuse him even more.  Sometimes less is more.   I feel is necessary to keep it as simple to help the OP.